# DP_jQuery is not defined after migration

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, migration, upgrade

I just update Jquery from 1.4.2 to 1.11.3 and UI from 1.7.2 to 1.11.4 and get one error with the datepicker UI:

> DP_jQuery is not defined

Here the code in concern:

```
DP_jQuery.datepicker._adjustDate('#'+$('.datepicker-tarifs').attr('id'), _step, 'M');
DP_jQuery.datepicker._adjustDate('#'+$('.datepicker-dispos').attr('id'), _step, 'M');
```

Any idea to migrate this? I can't find something similar on google

Comment: If all you removed were the two old files for jqueryui and jquery it sees that DP_JQuery must have been assigned to some DOM element inside one of them. Search for DP_JQuery in those files and move that assignment somewhere else.

Comment: Seems to be a deprecated object in Jqui, I just search the equivalent for the new version